# Django and NodeJs - Manage authentication

Tags: node.js, django, authentication

I'm using for my main app Django, and for a third party modules NodeJs with Express.
Now, i have to manage in a secure way the authentication of the third party app to my main app written in Django, that implements Tokens for API and default Django Authentication methods.

I have a bunch of ideas in order to achieve that, like:

- Create an API endpoint that checks the authentication via Token and call that API from the NodeJs App for every request (so, the auth Token it will be stored in a secure way to the backend of the third party app)
- Check the auth cookie from the NodeJs app

I think that the first approach is the way to go, but if anyone has some smarter ideas i'll be glad to listen them!

**Final remarks/notes**:
*These two apps are exposed to the users using a reverse proxy, and the authentication check can be managed directly backend-to-backend, and, if it's all ok, the application will be served to the user, without exposing any token authentication to the frontend*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok guys, i think that my answer needs to be shared: i've created a "validate" endpoint in my main Django app, and, using a custom middleware in NodeJS, on the third party app i'll check (directly in a backend-backend fashion way) the token validation and then serve the content.